# Function returns "Promise { <pending> }" as I expected a value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, blockchain

```
    export type DataType = number | string | string[] | Record;

    export class Block {
        private index: number;
        readonly timestamp = Date.now();
        private data: DataType;
        private hash: Promise;
        private previousHash: string;

        constructor(index: number, data: DataType, previousHash: string) {
            this.index = index;
            this.data = data;
            this.previousHash = previousHash;
            this.hash = this.calculateHash();
        }

        public getIndex = () => this.index;
        public getTimestamp = () => this.timestamp;
        public getData = () => this.data;
        public getHash = () => this.hash;
        public getPreviousHash = () => this.previousHash;

        public calculateHash = async (): Promise => {
            return (await import("crypto-js"))
                .SHA256(
                    +this.index +
                        JSON.stringify(+this.data) +
                        this.previousHash +
                        this.timestamp
                )
                .toString();
        };
    }
```

I wanted calculateHash to return a string value by using

```
toString()
```

at the return statement of a public function "calculateHash", and although I did, I got

```
Promise {  }
```

. Help! What's the problem?

Comment: "Promise { \<pending> }", not "Promise { }". Sorry.

Comment: `calculateHash` can't return anything BUT a promise, that's what `async` means - *this is a function that does asynchronous stuff so it will return a Promise that resolves to a value at a later time*

Comment: An async function returns a Promise... that's why.

Comment: It even says right there in your TypeScript code that the function is going to return a Promise: `public calculateHash = async (): Promise =>`. Anyway, import the crypto library at the top of your module, then simply use it without wrapping it in a Promise.

Comment: You can't force an async function to return the value it is supposed to resolve... that's the whole point of async: that it does not know the value at runtime and will resolve the value later. This feels like an XY problem: what you need to do is to actually await the `calculateHash()` call where you invoke it.

Comment: you'd need to `await xxx.calculateHash()` or `xxx.calculateHash().then(result => .....)`

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate of that infamous question; the real question here is why that Promise exists in the first place. Did you get this code from elsewhere? Or did you write it yourself? (sure, learning how to use Promises is never a bad idea, but the crypto-js module doesn't them for hash calculations)

Comment: Thank you for all your huge interests here, but what I really tried to learn by myself is how to use dynamic importing. and I figured out I should use async function with it to import like that code, and VSC told me that I have to return Promise<string>, not a string. that was my serious problem and the way to solve that prob was my focus. Now I simply import the module at the top of the module, all goes simply well. thank you.